# return value from string prototype using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using prototype method to replace comma in string but the function giving same string

```
String.prototype.removeLastComma = function(){
    return this.replace(/,/g, '.');
}
```

Comment: The code seems to work just fine for me. All comma's in the string get replaced.

Comment: It works fine... http://jsfiddle.net/Nea4t/

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `"a,b,c".removeLastComma();`?

Comment: Here is http://jsfiddle.net/Xuq3R/1/. I want to remove last comma of string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String.prototype.removeLastComma = function(){
    return this.replace(/,/g, '.');
}
```

Works just fine. I guess you're expecting the following effect:

```
var str = 'foo,bar,baz';
str.removeLastComma();
console.log(str); //foo.bar.baz
```

Unfortunately, this is not possible because the strings in JavaScript are [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Try this instead:

```
var str = 'foo,bar,baz';
str = str.removeLastComma();
console.log(str); //foo.bar.baz
```

**NOTE**: better call your method "removeCommas" or something like that. Remove last comma means that you're going to remove **only** the last one.

For removing the last comma you can use the following regular expression:

```
String.prototype.removeLastComma = function(){
    return this.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, '.');
}
```

Comment: Most elaborate answer: +1. Maybe he wants only the last comma replaced, though. That'd be a nice addition to the answer.

Comment: a,b,c,.removeLastComma(). I want to remove last comma only

Comment: Ok just included it in the answer, please verify it works as you expect :-).

Answer (score 0):

it works fine for me. For a sample implementation see: http://jsfiddle.net/9Hrzp/

```
String.prototype.removeLastComma = function(){
    return this.replace(/,/g, '.');
}

alert("foo,bar".removeLastComma());
```